# php cURL doesnt print out anything

Tags: php, curl, post

I am trying to send a HTML form POST data with a cURL, but it seems the response is always empty. I first save all the POST data in an array, and use an implode function. When I echo out the implode string it does return the values, but after the cURL it's just empty.

This is the setup. I call this function after submitting the form

```
$this->OCIcURL($this->request->post);

public function OCIcURL($post) {
    $data_oci = array();
    $items_oci = array();     

    $counter = 0;
    $data_oci['~caller'] = 'CTLG';
    foreach ($post['item'] as $key => $value)
    {
        $counter++;
        $data_oci['NEW_ITEM-DESCRIPTION[' . $counter . ']']         = $value;
        $data_oci['NEW_ITEM-MATNR[' . $counter . ']']               = "";
        $data_oci['NEW_ITEM-QUANTITY[' . $counter . ']']            = $post['amount'][$counter];
        $data_oci['NEW_ITEM-UNIT[' . $counter . ']']                = "";
        $data_oci['NEW_ITEM-PRICE[' . $counter . ']']               = $post['price'][$counter];
        $data_oci['NEW_ITEM-CURRENCY[' . $counter . ']']            = $this->session->data['currency'];
        $data_oci['NEW_ITEM-PRICEUNIT[' . $counter . ']']           = 1;
        $data_oci['NEW_ITEM-LEADTIME[' . $counter . ']']            = "";
        $data_oci['NEW_ITEM-VENDOR[' . $counter . ']']              = "";
        $data_oci['NEW_ITEM-VENDORMAT[' . $counter . ']']           = "";
        $data_oci['NEW_ITEM-MANUFACTCODE[' . $counter . ']']        = "";
        $data_oci['NEW_ITEM-MANUFACTMAT[' . $counter . ']']         = "";
        $data_oci['NEW_ITEM-MATGROUP[' . $counter . ']']            = "";
        $data_oci['NEW_ITEM-SERVICE[' . $counter . ']']             = "";
        $data_oci['NEW_ITEM-CONTRACT[' . $counter . ']']            = "";
        $data_oci['NEW_ITEM-CONTRACT_ITEM[' . $counter . ']']       = "";
        $data_oci['NEW_ITEM-EXT_QUOTE_ID[' . $counter . ']']        = "";
        $data_oci['NEW_ITEM-EXT_QUOTE_ITEM[' . $counter . ']']      = "";
        $data_oci['NEW_ITEM-EXT_PRODUCT_ID[' . $counter . ']']      = "";
        $data_oci['NEW_ITEM-ATTACHMENT[' . $counter . ']']          = "";
        $data_oci['NEW_ITEM-ATTACHMENT_TITLE[' . $counter . ']']    = "";
        $data_oci['NEW_ITEM-ATTACHMENT_PURPOSE[' . $counter . ']']  = "";
        $data_oci['NEW_ITEM-EXT_SCHEMA_TYPE[' . $counter . ']']     = "";
        $data_oci['NEW_ITEM-EXT_CATEGORY_ID[' . $counter . ']']     = "";
        $data_oci['NEW_ITEM-CUST_FIELD1[' . $counter . ']']         = 21;
        $data_oci['NEW_ITEM-PARENT_ID[' . $counter . ']']           = "";
        $data_oci['NEW_ITEM-ITEM_TYPE[' . $counter . ']']           = "";
    }

    foreach ($data_oci as $key => $value) 
    {
        $items_oci[] = $key . '=' . $value;
    }
    $string_oci = implode('&', $items_oci);
```

If I echo out the `$string_oci` I do get a result. After this I use the cURL to send the string to a link.

```
    $url = "http://localhost/test.php";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $string_oci);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , 1);  // RETURN THE CONTENTS OF THE CALL
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    var_dump($response);
}
```

The var_dump is always empty, returning `string(0) ""`. I also tried this on the live website, same result.

I used this piece of code to see any errors, but it seems it there arent any error at all, but the `var_dump` is always empty.

```
    if (curl_exec($ch) === FALSE) 
    {
        print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
        die("Curl error: " . curl_error($ch));
    }
    else
    {   
        curl_close($ch);
    }
```

Comment: What if you change `implode('&', $items_oci)`  into `http_build_query($data_oci)`? And show us `test.php` file

Comment: @Bart still no response

Comment: can you provide a small sample of $string_oci? Just var_dump it and send it here.

Comment: `NEW_ITEM-DESCRIPTION[1]=test&NEW_ITEM-QUANTITY[1]=20` @pr1nc3

Answer (score 0):

```
$endpoint="http://localhost/test3.php";
$session = curl_init($endpoint);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $string_oci);

curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($session);
var_dump($response);
curl_close($session);
```

You need a header in your curl request and your curl_init needs a url. Try the code i attach.